# Which package do we use to make HTTP connections?

Tags: android, http

I am trying to make HTTP get & post connections.
Which package is recommended for that?
Is it java.net or org.apache.http?
Does java.net comes included in the sdk?
Any reference/code to connection makin would be appreciable as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either [`URL/HttpUrlConnection`](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/pkg.html) or [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html) are fine choices, and both are part of the Android SDK. There are plenty of examples of using each, such as those linked to in the previous sentence. So long as you add the `INTERNET` permission to your application, you can largely ignore the fact that you are on Android and just use these APIs as if you were on desktop Java.